# Automatically apply a status for new orders woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to update the status of any and all orders (paid or unpaid) to completed, triggering the emails from woocommerce. Sounds counter intuitive but it needs to happen.

I thought something like this would work:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed','status_changed_processsing');
   function status_changed_processsing( $order_id, $checkout = null ) {
   global $woocommerce;
   $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
       //assign statu to that order
       $order->status = 'completed';
    }

}
```

But I have not been successful.

TIA. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with this one:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'status_changed_processsing' );
function status_changed_processsing( $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);

if (!empty($order)) {
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}
```

try like this